# How to keep text inserted in a html <textarea> after a wrong submission?

Tags: php, html, textarea

Suppose I have a form like this:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">

    Section1: <input name="section1" type="text"></br>
    Section2: <input name="section2" type="text"></br>

    Text:</br>
    <textarea name="post_text" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Usually if I wish to save content inserted in a field of the form I would use this statement:

```
Section1: <input name="section1" type="text" vale="value="<?php echo $_POST['section1']; ?>""></br>
```

This way if I make a mistake in submission (error control code is not posted) the values inserted will be kept, and there is no need to reinsert them.

However using it in the textarea tag it will not produce the desired result.

Any ideas on how to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly did you do for the textarea, and what was the result you did get?

Comment: Also there's a typo in your example, you probably meant "value", not "vale".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget about [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars). This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea

```
<textarea name="post_text" cols="100" rows="20"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['post_text']);?></textarea>
```

Comment: w3schools sucks, better link » https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 5):

You could use the same approach, but put the `echo` between the opening and closing `<textarea></textarea>` tags, as the `textarea` doesn't have a 'value' (as such) it has textual content:

```
<textarea name="post_text" cols="100" rows="20"><?php echo $_POST['textareaContent']; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$_POST` variable like this.

```
<textarea name="post_text" cols="100" rows="20"><?= isset($_POST['post_text'])?$_POST['post_text']:'' ?></textarea>
```

the inline conditional checks if the `$_POST['post_text']` is set to remove the NOTICE warning

Answer (score 0):

You would put it inside the `<textarea>` element like so:

```
<textarea name="post_text" cols="100" rows="20"><?php echo $_POST['post_text']; ?></textarea>
```

However, calling the $_POST element directly is not best practice.  You should rather do something like this:

```
<textarea name="post_text" cols="100" rows="20">
<?php echo $var = isset($_POST['post_text']) ? $_POST['post_text'] : ''; ?>
</textarea>
```

This stops an E_NOTICE error from being reported upon the first page-load.